# Joining table issues

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables that I'm looking to join:

```
pictures
--------
id   user_id    link

users
-----
id    name

votes
-----
id    user_id    picture_id
```

Want I want to do is find the total number of votes for every picture for the specific user logged in. Pretty much I loop every picture out and if the user has votes on the picture they can't vote on it again.

```
Desired output:
---------------

id    user_id    link    user_name    total_votes
1     5          [link]  Sean         5
```

So far I have something like this:

```
SELECT 
p.*, u.username, d.total_votes
FROM pictures p 
LEFT JOIN users u 
ON p.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN
(
select id, picture_id, count(id) as has_voted from votes
) d on d.picture_id = p.id
```

I get all the pictures but all the votes are being added up on the first record.

**EDIT**

Sorry for being so unclear

[image]

So this is every image in my database. Say I'm logged in as Sean (user_id 1) I want to show how many times I votes on each image.

user_id is who uploaded the image.

Comment: can you give smple records based on your desired output?

Comment: You want to select all pictures that this person has voted on?

Comment: Updated. Added an image to help clear things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Updated) Try:

```
Select p.id, p.user_id, p.link, u.name, count(v.id) As total_votes
from pictures p 
join users u on p.user_id = u.id
left join votes v on p.id = v.picture_id and v.user_id = ?
group by p.id
```

Comment: Very close but the correct username isn't displaying.. just mine (sean)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select p.id, p.user_id, p.link, u.name,(CASE count(v.id) WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE count(v.id) END ) as total_votes
    from pictures p       
    join users u on p.user_id = u.id 
    join votes v on (v.user_id = u.id and v.picture_id = p.id) 
where v.id is not null
    group by p.id
```

Comment: Close but this only shows MY images that I uploaded. I need all the images.

Comment: then use inner join, I have updated my solution to for inner join

Comment: Hmm, still not the desired outcome. Did you see the image I provided?

Comment: its working fine with my dataset. can you please share the result of above query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29776/discussion-between-alpesh-gediya-and-seanwm)

Comment: I get the results for pictures I have aleady voted on and thats correct. That being said, I still need ALL the images... even ones that I haven't voted on and are null.